# Unity server side c# scripts load at runtime

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, runtime, server-side-scripting

The subject is for advanced developers.

I want to load the game logic or some of it (c# files) at game load
just like other assets (assetbundles, audio, images), variables and configurations. I also want to be able to remotely change/update game logic.

I don't want to upload new build each and every-time I am changing one of my c# logic files.

My Regards,
Rami Ibrahim

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this maybe that'll work for you
https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/715891/Compiling-Csharp-Code-at-Runtime